# Optimization of a query which uses arithmetic operations in WHERE clause

Tags: cassandra, cql

I need to retrieve records where the expiration date is today. The expiration date is calculated dynamically using two other fields (`startDate` and `durationDays`):

```
SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE startDate + durationDays < currentDate()
```

Does it make sense to add two indexes for these two columns? Or should I consider adding a new column `expirationDate` and create an index for it only?

Comment: What is the schema for your table? If you ate going to retrieve the data based on the date, the date should be part of the key, maybe as part of a clustering key

Comment: The table contains an id, startDate, duration and some other fields. The question is, does it make sense to create an index for startDate and duration if they are used as params of arithmetic operation in WHERE clause?

Comment: if it is part of the WHERE, it must be part of the key. In Cassandra yo have to build the tables depending on the query that you need to execute, unlike relational databases

Comment: It makes sense. I'm wondering how does Cassandra handle such a filter as in my example? Does it make a full scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE startDate + durationDays < currentDate()
```

> I'm wondering how does Cassandra handle such a filter as in my example? Does it make a full scan?

First of all, your question is predicated on CQL's ability to perform (date) arithmetic.  It cannot.

```
> SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE startDate + durationDays < currentDate();
SyntaxException: line 1:43 no viable alternative at input '+' (SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE [startDate] +...)
```

Secondly the `currentDate()` function does not exist in Cassandra 3.11.4.

```
> SELECT currentDate() FROM system.local;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown function 'currentdate'"
```

That *does* work in Cassandra 4.0, which as it has not been released yet, you really shouldn't be using.

So let's assume that you've created your secondary indexes on `startDate` and `durationDays` and you're just querying on those, without any arithmetic.

Does it execute a full table scan?

**ABSOLUTELY.**

The reason, is that querying solely on secondary index columns does not have a partition key.  Therefore, it has to search for these values on all partitions on all nodes.  In a large cluster, your query would likely time out.

Also, when it finds matching data, it has to keep querying.  As those values are not unique; it's entirely possible that there are several results to be returned.  Carlos in 100% correct is advising you to rebuild your table based on what you want to query.

Recommendations:

- Try not to build a table with secondary indexes.  Like ever.
- If you have to build a table with secondary indexes, try to have a partition key in your `WHERE` clause to keep the query isolated to a single node.
- Any filtering on dynamic (computed) values needs to be done on the application side.
- In your case, it might make more sense to create a column called `expirationDate`, do your date arithmetic in your app, and then `INSERT` that value into your table.
- You'll also want follow the "time bucket" pattern for handling time series data (which is what this appears to be).  Say that `month` works as a "bucket" (it may or may not for your use case).  `PRIMARY KEY ((month),expirationDate,id)` would be a good key.  This way, all the subscriptions for a particular month are stored together, clustered by `expirationDate`, with `id` on the end to act as a tie-breaker for uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for very clear explanation and recommendations!

Comment: Regarding arithmetic operations, [this](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/operators.html) doc says that it's possible to add/substruct days to/from a date column. Does it mean that it's supported in SELECT only but not in WHERE?

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk Just tried out the example on that page.  Fails in 3.11.4, works in 4.0.  My guess is that the docs have been preemptively updated in anticipation of the release.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main differences between Cassandra and relational databases is that the definition of the tables depend on the query that will be used. The conditional of how the data will be retrieved (`WHERE statement`) should be included in the primary key as it will perform better than an index on the table.

There are multiple resources regarding the read path, and the quirks of primary keys vs indexes, this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuDJBTPdaOA) from the Cassandra Summit may be useful.